# TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]

Tags: python, pandas

TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine1 = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/db1')
engine2 = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/db2')
df = pd.read_sql_query("""
select id,text,created_date,is_read,to_user_id,is_new,url,text_ar,text_en from notifications_notification where created_date <= NOW() - interval '1 month'""",engine1)

 df= df.rename(columns={  'id':'original_id','text':'text','created_date':'created_date','is_read':'is_read','to_user_id':'to_user_id','is_new':'is_new','url':'url','text_ar':'text_ar','text_en':'text_en'})

df.index = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[us]')                                          

df.to_sql(name='notifications_notification_archive',con=engine2,if_exists='append')
```

Comment: You sure it's a `TypeError` and not a `ValueError`?

Comment: then how to fix it ?can you help please ?

Comment: is it a ValueError?

Comment: it's a TypeError

Comment: You have a non-numeric index, which Pandas is unable to cast to a date. Try changing it to something else?

Comment: I set index to False like this df.to_sql(name='notifications_notification_archive',con=engine2,if_exists='append',index=False)

Comment: but still getting the same error

Comment: because you're trying to convert your index to datetime with `df.index = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[us]') `

Comment: thanks Josh. i found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed now I've used the following lines :

```
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'])
df['created_date'] = df['created_date'].astype('datetime64[us]')
df.set_index('created_date', inplace=True)
df.to_sql(name='notifications_notification_archive',con=engine2,if_exists='append')
```